# How to remove "extras" from using java gradle shadow plugin

Tags: java, gradle, plugins, shadow

I'm using the gradle shadow plugin in my java project.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '7.0.0'
}
```

I used the following code to get rid of all the dependencies I could.

```
shadowJar {
    dependencies {
        exclude(dependency("org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT"))
        exclude(dependency("org.jetbrains:annotations:22.0.0"))
        exclude(dependency("com.comphenix.protocol:ProtocolLib:4.7.0"))
    }
}
```

However, I've got all these extra files in my jar file. I want to remove everything except what's in the "eu" folder and the "plugin.yml". How can I do this?

[image: Extra files]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use shadowJar {} unless you have to, just change "implementation" to "compileOnly" for the dependencies you don't want in the jar